# How to deal with a URL with the character 'é' in Safari?

Tags: php, html, url, href

I have files that I need to open/download from my webpage using links in a menu. My problem is when I try to open a file that has an 'É' in it with **Safari** (7.0.1). It's working with Firefox 26.0, Chrome 32.0.17 and IE.

The name in the URL is correct but the **Not Found** error shows a complete different name.

In the URL: `FORMULAIRE%20-%20ENVOI%20DE%20MESSAGE%20PAR%20TÉLÉCOPIEUR.doc`

The page error:

> FORMULAIRE - ENVOI DE MESSAGE PAR TÃ‰LÃ‰COPIEUR.doc was not found on
>   this server.

I tried `urlencode()`, `rawurlencode()`, `htmlspecialchar()` and my page's charset is set to UTF-8.

I absolutely need to keep the accents in the file's name. Someone have an idea?

Comment: Can`t you replace special chars to match ascii equivalent?

Comment: try this: `FORMULAIRE%20-%20ENVOI%20DE%20MESSAGE%20PAR%20T%C3%89L%C3%89COPIEUR.doc` in the url

Comment: I tried using the %C3%89 but my browser now see the char Ã‰ instead of 'É'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A handy workaround for dealing with tricky characters in URLs is to use their percent-encoded values.  In this case I believe you'd need to pass `%C3%89` in place of the `É`, just like passing a `%20` in place of a space.

So try this:

`FORMULAIRE%20-%20ENVOI%20DE%20MESSAGE%20PAR%20T%C3%89L%C3%89COPIEUR.doc`

It sounds like you're on a Mac, but if you have access to a Windows machine (vm or otherwise) Fiddler is a great swiss-army knife for all things HTTP, and it's tool menu includes a "Text Wizard" which can help with lots of text encoding/decoding.

Comment: When I use the percent-encoded values the 'É' is still buggy in the url and all the browser are not working. Yes I am using a Mac and Coda 2. Unfortunately I don't have access to a Windows machine to deal with it.

Comment: You could try Chrome or Firefox to determine if it's a Safari-specific issue, or if it might be with that specific site.  Percent-encoding is usually worth a try, but doesn't always work.

Comment: It's weird because when I use the link here : href="<?php echo ('formulaires/FORMULAIRE - ENVOI DE MESSAGE PAR TÉLÉCOPIEUR.doc'); ?>".... Safari cannot open the files but the other browser can.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the page in your local encoding and safari has some bug inside. You need to help the webbrowser by urlencoding, which seem to not work in php correctly. You have to replace those characters manually. It will depend on your locale (it seem to be french or something like that). See the `strtr` function in php and use association array from the characters in your locale to `%xx`/`%xx%xx`  representation... That is the only thing you can do (except using UTF instead of the french encoding.)

Comment: Is using the strtr function any different then changing the letter 'É' by %XX dirrectly in the href line?

Comment: I think you use urlencode which has some troubles recognizing the e character. You should implement your replacement of urlencode... or find out, why it is generating the awkward results...

Comment: It's weird because when I use the link here : href="<?php echo ('formulaires/FORMULAIRE - ENVOI DE MESSAGE PAR TÉLÉCOPIEUR.doc'); ?>".... Safari cannot open the files but the other browser can.

Answer (score 0):

Just met the same issue with safari, we found that the root cause is related to the [unicode normalization form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

- In safari, it's using NFC normalization form, so `É` is normalized to code point: 0019
- while in chrome, it's using NFD normalization form, so `É` is normalized to 2 code points: 0045, 0301

another example from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Example)
[image]

To handle this issue, the server side need to keep the strings in same unicode normalization form before using it. And it's better to avoid using these characters in URL

Answer (score -1):

You can't have accented characters in a URL. Only ASCII characters are permitted. See more info at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2

It's possible to rewrite URL's to handle accented characters, unfortunately I'm not up to scratch with URL Rewriting so I can't provide that for you - but it is possible.

Comment: Why is it possible to open my files with other browsers than Safari then? Am I missing something?